# Macro throwing Range: Method error on 50% of computers opening exact same file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file saved on the network that multiple people need to access. I added a macro to consolidate data from many tabs into one (Need multiple tabs for organization) to make some connections work much more effectively. The problem is that roughly half of the computers accessing the file consistently get a Range - Method error and I do not have access to those computers to try and debug...

I have walked through the code to find an error, but am unable to find one...at least one that I understand...? The structure seems fine as best I can tell...

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim MaxSheets As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim consolid As Worksheet
Dim summary As Worksheet
Dim PaidInv As Worksheet
Dim LRow As Long
Dim LInv As Long
Dim ConLRow As Long

'set initial values
Set wb = Workbooks("Wire Payments projections for Euro's")
Set consolid = wb.Sheets("Consolidation")
Set summary = wb.Sheets("Pay Summary")
Set PaidInv = wb.Sheets("Paid Invoices")

MaxSheets = Sheets.Count
LInv = 0
i = 1
j = 7

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'clear values between a2 and last row
With consolid
    ConLRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A2", .Cells(ConLRow, 7)).Clear
End With

For i = 1 To MaxSheets

    'loop through all sheets except those named
    If wb.Sheets(i).Name <> summary.Name And wb.Sheets(i).Name <> PaidInv.Name And wb.Sheets(i).Name <> consolid.Name Then
        With wb.Sheets(i)
            'Find last row on the sheet (for Search limiting)
            LRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

            'search for first empty cell between row 7 and last row on sheet
            For j = 7 To LRow
                If .Cells(j, 2).Value = "" And LInv = 0 Then
                    LInv = j
                End If
            Next j

        End With

        With consolid
            'Find last used row
            ConLRow = .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            'Assume LInv returned a value greater than 7, copy information to cells.
            If LInv > 7 Then
                .Range(.Cells(ConLRow + 1, 1), .Cells((ConLRow + (LInv - 7)), 1)) = wb.Sheets(i).Range("d1")
                .Range(.Cells(ConLRow + 1, 2), .Cells((ConLRow + (LInv - 7)), 2)) = wb.Sheets(i).Range("b1")
                wb.Sheets(i).Range(wb.Sheets(i).Cells(7, 2), wb.Sheets(i).Cells(LInv, 7)).Copy
                consolid.Cells(ConLRow + 1, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End If

        End With

End If

LInv = 0

Next i

'format columns and enter row headers
With consolid
            .Columns(4).NumberFormat = "m/d/y"
            .Columns(5).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
            .Columns(6).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
            .Cells(1, 1) = "Vendor Number"
            .Cells(1, 2) = "Vendor Name"
            .Cells(1, 3) = "Invoice ID"
            .Cells(1, 4) = "Due Date"
            .Cells(1, 5) = "Native Inv Amount"
            .Cells(1, 6) = "USD Invoice Amount"
            .Cells(1, 7) = "Mark to Pay"
End With

'return user to summary tab
summary.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
summary.Range("A1").Select

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

For half of us using the macro, everything works perfectly. For the other half they get a Range - Method error.

Comment: Probably not your problem, but `i` and `j` should be `Dim`med as `Long`

Comment: `MaxSheets` should probably have the workbook added to it `(wb.Sheets.Count)` in case multiple workbooks are open.  What line do they get the error on?

Comment: Less than cooperative co-workers still have not sent me a screencap after hitting debug, Just of the error.

Thank you both for the suggestions to improve efficiency/"Safety"

Comment: `Set wb = Workbooks("Wire Payments projections for Euro's")` will fail ("Subscript out of range") on any PC with "hide extensions for known file types" turned off in windows Explorer options.  Using the full name including extension *always* works.